# Why can't I leave a TextBox using tab?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I have this code:

```
public static void AddDefaultTextFromTag(params TextBox[] textBoxes)
{
    foreach (TextBox oTextBox in textBoxes)
    {
        bool isPasswordChar = oTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar;

        oTextBox.Enter += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            if (((TextBox)sndr).Text == ((TextBox)sndr).Tag.ToString())
            {
                ((TextBox)sndr).Text = "";
                ((TextBox)sndr).UseSystemPasswordChar = isPasswordChar;
                ((TextBox)sndr).ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
            }
        };

        oTextBox.Leave += (sndr, evnt) =>
        {
            if (((TextBox)sndr).Text.Trim().Count() == 0)
            {
                ((TextBox)sndr).UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
                ((TextBox)sndr).CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Normal;
                ((TextBox)sndr).Text = ((TextBox)sndr).Tag.ToString();
                ((TextBox)sndr).ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
            }
        };

        if (oTextBox.Text.Trim().Count() == 0)
        {
            oTextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar = false;
            oTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Normal;
            oTextBox.Text = oTextBox.Tag.ToString();
            oTextBox.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        }
    }
}
```

But when the `TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar` I input in this method's parameter is true and it's `TextBox.Text` property is empty, the `TextBox` can't leave using a `Tab` button on the keyboard, only a `MouseClick` can be used to lose the focus of that `TextBox`.

Why is this happening?

My code is in C#, framework 4, build in VS2010 Pro, project is in WinForms.
I use a TextBox from the VS ToolBox.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a suggestion: Why not create two methods (Enter and Leave) and attach that as event handlers to all your text boxes instead of using a custom delegate for each one? (I don't think they are reused in this case, but I'm not sure) And instead of duplicating code you can run the Leave event handler on all of them.

Comment: @Joey The anonymous methods are absolutely reused. During compilation, each anonymous method is converted to an instance method of the class, and that method is used for the event handlers. So don't worry :)

Comment: Ah, thanks MD.Unicorn. Then one can ignore that part and just use the last suggestion of reducing code duplication ;)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't leave the textbox is because you are changing the CharacterCasing property in the textbox.

Not sure why it works like this, but it has happened to me before, what I ended up doing was capture the keypress event, and if it was a letter I'd switch it to it's uppercase value. It's not optimal, but it works

I did something similar to this (writing it from the top of my head, but it should work):

```
void YourTextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar))
    {
        if (this.CharacterCasing == CharacterCasing.Upper && char.IsLower(e.KeyChar))
        {
            this.Text = this.Text.Insert(this.SelectionStart, char.ToUpper(e.KeyChar) + string.Empty);
            this.SelectionStart++;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (this.CharacterCasing == System.Windows.Forms.CharacterCasing.Lower && char.IsUpper(e.KeyChar))
        {
            this.Text = this.Text.Insert(this.SelectionStart, char.ToLower(e.KeyChar) + string.Empty);
            this.SelectionStart++;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You also should use the new keyword to "override" (I know that's not the right term here) the Character casing, so it doesn't do it's own thing

```
public new CharacterCasing CharacterCasing { get; set; }
```

The code basically checks if the pressed key is a letter, then, if it's marked as Upper, and the char is lower, replaces it with it's upper version (in the position of the cursor) then moves the cursor to the next part, and Viceversa (toLower)

NOTE:
This code will have may (should) have some trouble if the user has more than one character selected (SelectionLenght > 0), if you want to keep the normal Textbox functionality, you should delete all the selected characters

Answer (score 0):

So I set up a WinForms app, drew two textboxes, set one to UseSystemPasswordChar=true then set it up like so:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Tag = "test2";
        textBox1.Tag = "test1";

        TextBox[] tb = { textBox1, textBox2 };
        AddDefaultTextFromTag(tb);
    }
```

Your function works fine and I have no problems tabbing through the controls on the form no matter what the textboxes contain. (added a button also that does nothing for tabbing test) so... no repro unless my test setup is not valid

Comment: I drag tools from the toolbox. The `TabIndex` is set automatically by VS and the `TabStop` is set to true.

Answer (score 0):

What I found in the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9288900/why-is-the-changing-of-textbox-usesystempasswordchar-property-invokes-the-textbo) was the solution for me. Instead of setting UseSystemPasswordChar to true and then to false, you can set PasswordChar to '●' and then to '\0' to have normal text. You should not set the UseSystemPasswordChar because it has precedence over PasswordChar.