# Why is the changing of TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar property invokes the TextBox.Focus() method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I post a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272719/why-cant-i-leave-a-textbox-using-tab#comment11695459_9272719) here in stackoverflow entitled *Why can't I leave a TextBox using tab?*. In my code, I change the value of `TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar` property in the `TextBox.Leave` event and it prevents it to focus to other control through `TAB` key by invoking the `TextBox.Focus()` method whenever the line of setting the `TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar` is executed.

Thomas Software [answered](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/8de8bc99-de90-4dc9-ab00-ce691af0a0cf/#215e226b-9fda-40c3-8f2c-89520a4e602c) it in MSDN Forums:

> During my testing, I tried implmenting it as normal events on the `TextBox` as well, with the same result.  I did notice that it does temporarily lose focus when the `TAB` was pressed, but it then immediately refocused the control when `UseSystemPasswordChar` was set.

My question is **Why is the changing of TextBox.UseSystemPasswordChar property invokes the TextBox.Focus() method and how can I prevent it from invoking?**

Comment: What do you want to prevent the event from getting invoked?

Comment: @gideon sorry, it should be `TextBox.Focus()` **method**.

Comment: John Isaiah Carmona have you found another solution? I think that the one suggested by @silenttone works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason this happens. A workaround is to set a custom password char with:
`TextBox.PasswordChar = '●'`

Reset it to normal text with:

`TextBox.PasswordChar = '\0'`

This doesn't trigger focus change IME.